# How to convert the normalized units of pulse amplitude od Qiskit Pulse to Hz or something else?

Tags: qiskit

If you have used a Qiskit Pulse then you know that the amlitudes are normalized from 0 to 1. I need to convert this value to Hz or Joules or whatever. This scaling factor also depends on the backend I am using.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.